# Three.js: How to animate particles along a line

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, particles

I'm trying to animate particles along a path similar to this chrome expriement: http://armsglobe.chromeexperiments.com/

I've tried digging into the source of this project, and what I've groked so far is that they are using a built in curve method  .getPoitns() to generate about 30 points on their lines.

Is there a better example on what I'm trying to accomplish? Is there a method for getting points on the line than using the .lerp() method 30 times to get 30 points?  Should I just use TWEEN animations?

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: The author wrote a blog post about the arms globe thing which you may find helpful or at least interesting. http://mflux.tumblr.com/post/28367579774/armstradeviz

Comment: That's an awesome write up, but he glosses over the particle animation.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I think I remember reading another write up where he went into more detail about the particles. If I can find it I will post it.

Comment: I can't find it, but he seems to update the position of each vertex of the line that the particle system particles are attached to. It can be seen here: http://armsglobe.chromeexperiments.com/js/visualize.js . The part that seems to update the vertex positions is the pSystem.update function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've figured out a solution, not sure if it's the best or not, but it works well.

You can find a demo on JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L4beLw26/

```js
//First create the line that we want to animate the particles along
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-800, 0, -800));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(800, 0, 0));

var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
var startPoint = line.geometry.vertices[0];
var endPoint = line.geometry.vertices[1];
scene.add(line);


//next create a set of about 30 animation points along the line
var animationPoints = createLinePoints(startPoint, endPoint);

//add particles to scene
for ( i = 0; i < numParticles; i ++ ) {
  var desiredIndex = i / numParticles * animationPoints.length;
  var rIndex = constrain(Math.floor(desiredIndex),0,animationPoints.length-1);
  var particle = new THREE.Vector3();
  var particle = animationPoints[rIndex].clone();
  particle.moveIndex = rIndex;
  particle.nextIndex = rIndex+1;
  if(particle.nextIndex >= animationPoints.length )
    particle.nextIndex = 0;
  particle.lerpN = 0;
  particle.path = animationPoints;
  particleGeometry.vertices.push( particle );
}

//set particle material
var pMaterial = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x00FF00,
  size: 50,
  map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
    "assets/textures/map_mask.png"
  ),
  blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
  transparent: true
});


var particles = new THREE.ParticleSystem( particleGeometry, pMaterial );
particles.sortParticles = true;
particles.dynamic = true;
scene.add(particles);


//update function for each particle animation
particles.update = function(){
  // var time = Date.now()
  for( var i in this.geometry.vertices ){
    var particle = this.geometry.vertices[i];
    var path = particle.path;
    particle.lerpN += 0.05;
    if(particle.lerpN > 1){
      particle.lerpN = 0;
      particle.moveIndex = particle.nextIndex;
      particle.nextIndex++;
      if( particle.nextIndex >= path.length ){
        particle.moveIndex = 0;
        particle.nextIndex = 1;
      }
    }

    var currentPoint = path[particle.moveIndex];
    var nextPoint = path[particle.nextIndex];


    particle.copy( currentPoint );
    particle.lerp( nextPoint, particle.lerpN );
  }
  this.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
};




function createLinePoints(startPoint, endPoint){
  var numPoints = 30;
  var returnPoints = [];
  for(i=0; i <= numPoints; i ++){
    var thisPoint = startPoint.clone().lerp(endPoint, i/numPoints);
    returnPoints.push(thisPoint);
  }
  return returnPoints;
}

function constrain(v, min, max){
  if( v < min )
    v = min;
  else
    if( v > max )
      v = max;
  return v;
}
```

and then in the animation loop:

```js
particles.update();
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if anyone else can't see the snippets working, but I took the answer that jigglebilly provided and put it into a full html page and is working. Just so that if you want to see a working version. `
    
        
        
        Particle Test

```
<script src="../js/three.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, (window.innerWidth) / (window.innerHeight), 100, 10000);
    var container = document.getElementById("containerElement");
    var numParticles = 40;
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff });
    //First create the line that we want to animate the particles along
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-800, 0, -800));
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(800, 0, 0));

    var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
    var startPoint = line.geometry.vertices[0];
    var endPoint = line.geometry.vertices[1];
    scene.add(line);


    //next create a set of about 30 animation points along the line
    var animationPoints = createLinePoints(startPoint, endPoint);
    var particleGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    //add particles to scene
    for ( i = 0; i < numParticles; i ++ ) {

        var desiredIndex = i / numParticles * animationPoints.length;
        var rIndex = constrain(Math.floor(desiredIndex),0,animationPoints.length-1);
        var particle = new THREE.Vector3();
        var particle = animationPoints[rIndex].clone();
        particle.moveIndex = rIndex;
        particle.nextIndex = rIndex+1;
        if(particle.nextIndex >= animationPoints.length )
            particle.nextIndex = 0;
        particle.lerpN = 0;
        particle.path = animationPoints;
        particleGeometry.vertices.push( particle );
    }

    //set particle material
    var pMaterial = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x00FF00,
        size: 50,
        blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
        transparent: true
    });


    var particles = new THREE.ParticleSystem( particleGeometry, pMaterial );
    particles.sortParticles = true;
    particles.dynamic = true;
    scene.add(particles);

    function UpdateParticles(){
        // var time = Date.now()
        for( var i = 0; i < particles.geometry.vertices.length; i++ ){
            var particle = particles.geometry.vertices[i];
            var path = particle.path;
            particle.lerpN += 0.05;
            if(particle.lerpN > 1){
                particle.lerpN = 0;
                particle.moveIndex = particle.nextIndex;
                particle.nextIndex++;
                if( particle.nextIndex >= path.length ){
                    particle.moveIndex = 0;
                    particle.nextIndex = 1;
                }
            }

            var currentPoint = path[particle.moveIndex];
            var nextPoint = path[particle.nextIndex];


            particle.copy( currentPoint );
            particle.lerp( nextPoint, particle.lerpN );
        }
        particles.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    };

    animate();

    function createLinePoints(startPoint, endPoint){
        var numPoints = 30;
        var returnPoints = [];
        for(i=0; i <= numPoints; i ++){
            var thisPoint = startPoint.clone().lerp(endPoint, i/numPoints);
            returnPoints.push(thisPoint);
        }
        return returnPoints;
    }

    function constrain(v, min, max){
        if( v < min )
            v = min;
        else
        if( v > max )
            v = max;
        return v;
    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        render();
    }

    function render() {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        UpdateParticles();
    }
</script>
```

`

This uses three.js R67.