# Size of sprites along geometry Three.js

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, particles

I want to show an animation of sprites along the figure. specifically moving sprites walking figure.
so as shown here:

```
http://armsglobe.chromeexperiments.com/
```

I am basing on the answer to this question:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898635/three-js-how-to-animate-particles-along-a-line
```

[image]

This is my result, sprites start out small, then they get bigger. I want who are the same size.

but I need you all sprites the same size. I looked at the code but does not know what to do for all sprites the same size .

I would greatly appreciate if you can help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sprite cannot use `sizeAttenuation` feature to be false. 
You need to use `Pointcloud`. 
http://codepen.io/seanseansean/pen/EaBZEY

Parameter in pontCloud material you searching for is the `sizeAttenuation= false`.

Will make all particles size relative to canvas size. will not change in perspective.

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();      
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3() );
var size = 32; // means 32px

var sectorIcon = new THREE.PointCloud( geometry, new THREE.PointCloudMaterial( { size: size, color: new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ), depthTest: 1, depthWrite: false,  opacity: 0.5, sizeAttenuation: false, blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending, transparent: true, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("img/sectors/"+value.image_file) } ) );
```

Comment: thanks for answering. then if I use PointCloud, I can resize the PointCloud?. My concern is that, if I use PointCloud instead of sprite, it will run my code? The PointClouds will be touring geometry as they once did sprites?

Comment: You can change PointCloud.material.size = 38 for 38px at anytime. But only for all points in PointCloud. In you need more different sizes of particles, use more PointClouds.

Comment: I explain. in the code that I have, sprites begin from small to large. I just need all the same size. how can I do this?.

Comment: Pointcloud is not affected by perspective, that means all particles have size in PX if you use PC.material.sizeAttenuation = false.

Comment: That means if you are distanced more or less, it have still absolute size. If you use sizeAttenuation: true, it will be affected of perspective distortion.

If you have more verticles in one pointcloud, all of them have the same size  - always.

Comment: Thanks, now I have more clear. if use PointCloud instead of sprites, work the same code as I need ?.

Comment: Should be. You can animate verticles positions in one PointCloud Geometry (better for performance in case od thousands), or animate each PointCloud as a object. by changing position. Result should looks like similar, moving particles not affected by the perspective distortion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97430/discussion-between-o11ce-and-martin).

Comment: then I will use point clouds. I want to know if there is an easy way in which several PointClouds, the PointClouds move along a line ?.